# Convert an imported land surface temperature feature collection to an image

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, landsat

Adopting Landsat data I have managed to calculate the land surface temperature (LST), longitude and latitude for pixels in a polygon in 1984 and 2020 and export as a CSV file. I then used Python to calculate the difference in LST between 1984 and 2020 and imported the pixel LST difference, longitude, latitude into GEE as a FeatureCollection. Please see: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0f04cfab35e1702ac19decad6820ec07

Here is my attempt, using `ee.FeatureCollection.reduceToImage`, to add the LST difference map in the GEE code editor:

```
var LST = LST_1984_2020_Diff
 .reduceToImage({
   properties: ['LST_Difference'],
   reducer: ee.Reducer.first()})
 .clip(roi);

Map.addLayer(LST, {min:0.3, max:1.7, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
]},'LST_1984_2020_Diff');
```

But when I execute the code nothing appears on the map. Surely I am missing something so my question is, how do I visualize this LST FeatureCollection?

Here is the LST data `LST_1984_2020_Diff` which I have imported as a FeatureCollection, I also assigned the Longitude and Latitude in the advanced options in the 'Upload a new csv asset' tab:

```
LST_Difference,Latitude,Longitude
0.9914486704818728,35.70171793214922,139.56823609295515
1.3989379350116344,35.701721875790994,139.56856760619385
1.409341618242312,35.70172581852008,139.5688991194969
1.6231792407071453,35.70172976033651,139.56923063286442
1.226530659743105,35.70173370124028,139.56956214629622
0.9803960258391271,35.70173764123139,139.5698936597924
0.6247544227397306,35.70174158030984,139.57022517335292
0.31615998897563813,35.70174551847562,139.57055668697777
0.9567983482606905,35.70144752505799,139.56824092830144
1.2096579840384791,35.701451468660714,139.5685724404215
1.3440503379708844,35.70145541135077,139.56890395260592
1.5768031615315898,35.701459353128186,139.56923546485473
1.238696529619915,35.701463293992944,139.5695669771679
1.1707471229797122,35.701467233945046,139.56989848954544
0.7547827552330624,35.70147117298451,139.57023000198728
0.53947032244713,35.7014751111113,139.57056151449348
```

Also, just in case, here is the coordinates of the roi:

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[139.56806768251147, 35.70183281442274],
          [139.56806768251147, 35.70133619976342],
          [139.5708464510509, 35.70133619976342],
          [139.5708464510509, 35.70183281442274]]])
```

Comment: Could you please share your `users/comalley54/1984_2020_LST_Diff` asset with the public? That will allow us to run the script as intended.

Comment: Dear Sean, thank you for the comment. I believe I have done this now, here is also a link to the asset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/comalley54/1984_2020_LST_Diff. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have just realized that the above code does work, it is just that the pixel size which is added to the map is very small. Therefore I didn't see the pixels! If anyone is interested where I got the information for this code it is in GEE tables and vectors video: https://youtu.be/XLE-apehUCk